# Read Network Traffic with javascript and selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want to read network traffic of my webpage ('some url') with javascript and selenium web driver. I have my code here:

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 30000 } );
    await driver.get("url...");
```

and with driver I want to read network traffic.
I suppose is with DevToolsProtocol but i don't know how to do it with Javascript.

I have tried something such as driver.sendAndGetDevToolsCommands('something'), but i don't know how to continue.

Comment: Not with selenium. Consider puppeteer instead

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, i have tried it with puppeteer but I get null HTTPResponses, do you know why?